# Inline entity form module fails when creating a new node and the reference method is Views

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a Drupal 8, core version:8.8.x project, i'm using **inline entity form** module(latest version) for entity reference fields. Also i have tried using entity connect module but it caused various issues. The problem is when creating a new node, using the **inline entity form** and the **reference method** of field is **Views: Filter by an entity reference view** this error is coming up:

```
This entity (node: newNode) cannot be referenced.
```

How to reproduce:

1. Install inline entity form module
2. Create an entity reference field in any content type with **Views: Filter by an entity reference view** as reference method.
3. To your content type manage form display choose **inline entity form - complex** for widget.
4. Add new node for your content type, press add new node to your reference field, fill the modal form, publish it and press create new node(referenced node).
5. Lastly publish and save your node.

I tried some patches published to project issues but most of them are not applying at all. I would appreciate any ideas for solving it or suggestions for using a similar module.

Comment: Did you assign a specific View Display (of type Entity reference) under the **Views: Filter by an entity reference view** option? Do you want your reference field to be able to assign both existing nodes, and also create new ones with the Inline entity form? Because if not, you don't need the Views filter option, right?

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply, i have assigned a specific view display and yes i'd like to add existing and create new nodes. @prkos

Answer (score 0):

See patch located

[Drupal core patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2800875)

#42 works with Drupal 8.9.2 give that a try, it should fix your problem.